# JqueryMobile Loading spinner for a function call

Tags: jquery-mobile

I would like to show the loading spinner while a function is running in jquerymobile.
The function is non ajax its just going to calculate some values and save to a sqlite db.
I have searched and i keep finding the same examples saying use $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg(); etc.

example

```
function loading()
{
    $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();

    //Do Some Stuff in here

    $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
}
```

Thanks In advance.
Lmac

Comment: What is the problem/question? If the spinner doesn't appear to spin or even load its because your calculations are taking-up all the CPU. You may be able to place delays in a loop or something to allow the spinner to draw.

Comment: Hi Jasper,  thanks for your reply do you have any examples of your delays method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply call:

```
 $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();
```

at the beginning of your function as you mentioned but on a callback of your function

```
$.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
```

If you wanted the loader to appear for a certain period of time you could use:

```
$.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();
var wait = setTimeout(function(){
    $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
},400);
```

Comment: Hi roman, i tried your setTimeout method but it did not work. Thanks for your replay

Comment: Timeout is a means of keeping the loader on the screen for a certain period of time, it works but it may not be what you are looking for.  http://jsfiddle.net/ZFLWN/

Comment: `$.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();
    setTimeout(function () { // Function in here  $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();}, 500);` worked i also think jasper was correct with max cpu

Answer (score 1):

Use $.mobile.loading( 'show' ); and $.mobile.loading( 'hide' ); instead. Functions above are deprecated from jquery mobile documentation.